# Importing models between apps in Django 1.9

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm just starting a new project in Django 1.9, and for some reason can't import my models from one app to another. Below is my file structure:

```
├── apps
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main
        |--__init__.py
        |--models.py
    └── contacts
        |--__init__.py
        |--models.py
├── config
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

And my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.main',
    'apps.contacts',
]
```

For some reason, since upgrading to 1.9, this import

```
from apps.main.models import BaseUser
```

in contacts/models.py is returning the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   
File "/Users/kendallcole/.virtualenvs/trickledowncrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   
File "/Users/kendallcole/.virtualenvs/trickledowncrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()   
File "/Users/kendallcole/.virtualenvs/trickledowncrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   
File "/Users/kendallcole/.virtualenvs/trickledowncrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)   
File "/Users/kendallcole/.virtualenvs/trickledowncrm/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   
File "/Users/kendallcole/Desktop/trickledowncrm/apps/contacts/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apps.main.models import BaseUser 
ImportError: No module named main.models
```

Comment: Does this issue persist if you import the Models individually instead of via `*`?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Did anything else change aside from the Django version? A new virtual environment? Change to PYTHONPATH? Anything else?

Comment: in the [change log](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9) of 1.9 documentation they mention about importing modules have changed but i cant figured it out how to work with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem as resolved it using the [Django apps registry described here](http://www.ampeeg.com/dj191/ref/applications.html#django.apps.apps).

I was trying to import the models from another app called `warehouse`:

```
from warehouse.models import Member
```

That gave me the same error you had. I resolved it by assigning the model to a variable instead of trying to import the `warehouse` models:

```
from django.apps import apps

class ModelFromAnotherApp(models.Model):
    ...
    def method_using_model_from_another_app:
        member = apps.get_model('warehouse.Member')
        x = members.objects.filter(...)
    ...
```

Comment: Excellent example of how to post a good answer referencing an external resource!

Comment: Minor update: The code did not work for Python 3.x and Django 4.0.x. Instead use, member = apps.get_model('APP_NAME.MODEL_NAME'). Great answer though; It got me out of a tough spot. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I started a project in 1.8 then upgraded to 1.9. Everything worked fine until I created a new app after the 1.9 upgrade. I just the deleted the apps.py file in the new app, and everything worked fine again. Not sure why that was an issue though

Comment: Hi. I had the same problem and your answer helped me. Can you please tell me why deleting apps.py helped?

Answer (score 1):

Change your apps directory name to app. If you created your apps using startapp command, then there is a file called apps.py. I think that's causing the conflict.

```
├── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main
        |--__init__.py
        |--models.py
    └── contacts
        |--__init__.py
        |--models.py
├── config
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── wsgi.py
```