# How can I use a class from another app in Django

Tags: django

I have a blog app and a video app in the same directory in my django project. I am trying to a add a model from my video app called video, to my blog/views.py so I can access it by using

```
Video.object.all()
```

I tried doing this

```
from video.models import Video
```

and

```
from Models.video import Video
```

and

```
import video
```

but none of these are working. How do I change my code to access that class

Comment: You need to list your models here.

Comment: Also, you need to tell us what kind of error do you get.

Comment: Are both apps listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app

Comment: @Deva that didn't work. It just cleared up my ide but I am getting an error saying there is no module named src

Comment: @Ahmed this seems to work now

Comment: @Ahmed this seems to work now   from video.models import Video. But my Pycharm ide has warning lines under video and Video. The error message says "this inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing this is possible in  limited but useful amount of cases. Top level and class level items are supported better than instance items

Comment: what is project directory structure?

Comment: Your example cites Video.``object``.all(). This should be plural; ``objects``