# not able to import a file from an app to another

Tags: python, django, importerror

I have a django project with srtucture like this:

**main_project**

----main_project

<------libs

<<---------exceptions.py

----project_a

----project_b

In the views.py of *project_a* I am trying to import a folder named **libs** of *main_project* and a file from *libs*  called *exceptions.py*, but I am getting the error
`ImportError: No module named libs.exceptions`

My code is :

```
from main_project.libs.exceptions import (
    APIException400,
    APIException405,
    APIException403,
    exception_handler_dispatcher,
)
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?
With reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407131/5080347 answer I even tried :

```
from main_project.main_project.libs.exceptions import (
        APIException400,
        APIException405,
        APIException403,
        exception_handler_dispatcher,
    )
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Does `libs` contain the `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: Added `__init.py__` file still not working

Comment: No it's `__init__.py` and not `__init.py`, without the file python consider libs as ordinary folder and not package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to add `__init__.py` to `libs` directory.

> The `__init__.py` is used to initialize Python packages. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to better understand how things are working.

**Your structure should looks as follow:**

```shell
    project/
    |   
    |-- __init__.py
    |   
    |-- module_a/
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |
    |   |-- file1.py
    |   |
    |   |-- file2.py
    |
    |-- module_b/
    |   |
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |
    |   |-- file1.py
    |   |
    |   |-- submodule/
    |   |   |--__init__.py
    |   |   |
    |   |   |-- file1.py
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import using `from main_project.libs.exceptions`, python expects that `main_project` is the package and `libs` and `exceptions` are submodules. So there must be a file named `__init__.py` in those directories. The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. For further reading please refer to  [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).