# I want to create a reusable function in Django

Tags: django, django-mailer

I am new to django and have been working on a project where i need to send regular mails to my clients from different modules in my django project.

I wanted to know if there is any provision in django using which i can create a reusable component which can be used globally in my project.

The purpose is to create a mail sending function using a third party api and to call it from anywhere in my application just by passing the required parameters.

Comment: You can define function inside any app. Also you can use it anywhere in your application

Comment: @itzMEonTV
yes i do know of that option existing in Django. I just needed to know if i can create a separate file/function which is not related to any modules but only to that purpose for which it is being used.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have a single django app in your project, you could define all your reusable methods inside a `methods.py` file in your app folder and then import it to use the functions.

If you have multiple apps, Then define create this `methods.py` in one of your app. Now lets say your project name is `coolprojectname` and the name of app which has `methods.py` is `appwithmethodsscript`, then you can use

`from coolprojectname.appwithmethodsscript import methods`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app)

Comment: Dashes (`-`) aren't allowed in module names, and module names should be lower case.

Comment: Thanks @Anuj
Even i had the same thing in mind. But as some frameworks allow the option to create a common plugin like class to be called from any where i thought django also might have one.
Thanks

Comment: @VivekCu If you were satisfied with the answer can you mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

Django follows the rules of python.

As such, you can define a function **anywhere**, and import it wherever you want to use it.

The only condition for this to work is to have your packages following the right structure (i.e. a directory that has an `__init__.py` file)

Comment: Thanks @Adelin 
Even i was thinking of the same process.
As I didn't want the mail send (a common function) to reside in a module not related to it, i asked that question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Probably you'd be better of adding that function to the 'UserManager'. Also, don't forget that if this answers your question, it should be flagged as such