# Django +2 ImportError: cannot import model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hi have been working with Django and i want to have relations bettwen model i have the following structure 
[image]

on **posts/models.py**

from django.db import models

    class Post(models.Model):

(SKIP ATTRIBUTES)

and then on **comments/model.py**
from django.db import models 
**from posts.models import Post**

class Comment(models.Model): 
    **post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')**

In a nutshell im trying to import posts model into comment model and i get the error that 
cannot import name 'Post' from 'posts.models , how should import posts model to avoid this issue ?

**from posts.models import Post
ImportError: cannot import name 'Post' from 'posts.models**

Comment: Your structure and import statement seems fine. Make sure, you have saved your files, and try restarting the server.

Comment: Also, have you added your Post model in the admin.py of the posts app?

Comment: @DarshanChheda yes ,i have my Post model on admin.py the strange thing here is that from posts.models import Post its working there but not when i import con Comment model

Comment: Please provide the code snippet. Might be some very minor unseen issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are also importing comments.models in posts.models,
This may happen due to circular import. Try this:

```
from posts import models as posts_models
```

and

```
post = models.ForeignKey(posts_models.Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'posts.models' has no attribute 'Post'

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are importing

Comment: error where related to wrong imports that i wasn't using , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tell me if it helps

```
from DjangoPost.posts.models import Post
```

instead of

```
from posts.models import Post
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DjangoPost'

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app, assuming it is similar to your problem