# How to import models frome one Django app to another?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried to import models from one app to another by using the following:

`from ..appName.models import className`
also

```
from appName.models import className
```

but **attempted relative import beyond top-level package** error occured. My aim is to create a student management system. In one app i created the model and in another app i try to retrive data from that model but failed to do it..

```
├───Save_to_database
│   ├───HelpingClass
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───Search
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───StudentApp
│   └───__pycache__
└───templates
```

I want to import models from save_to_database into Search.

And yes i added the app in settings.py

Excuse my english

Comment: This answer could be helpful:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django : Unable to import model from another App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
├───Save_to_database
│   ├───HelpingClass
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───Search
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───StudentApp
│   └───__pycache__
└───templates
```

I want to import models from save_to_database into Search.

And yes i added the app in settings.py