# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat_app_backend.authentication' in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a Django project and getting the following error when trying to import the User model from chat_app_backend.authentication in my models.py file:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat_app_backend.authentication'`

Here's the code from my models.py file from my chat.models:

```
from django.db import models
from chat_app_backend.authentication.models import User

class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='chatroom_pictures/', null=True, blank=True)
    number_of_users = models.IntegerField()
    messages = models.TextField()
```

Here's my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig'
]
```

here's my models.py of my authentication.models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/')
```

And here's my project's file structure:

```
chat_app_backend
    -chat_app_backend
        -authentication
        -chat
        -chat_app_backend
```

I have tried the solution provided in this post ([Django : Unable to import model from another App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406662/django-unable-to-import-model-from-another-app)), but it did not work for me.

Apparently, its not the issue related to only the user model, when I try to access even the UserSerializer, which is in the authentication app(serializers.py), its giving me the same error.

```
from chat_app_backend.authentication.serializers import UserSerializer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat_app_backend.authentication'
```

here's the code for the serializers.py in the chat app:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ChatRoom
from chat_app_backend.authentication.serializers import UserSerializer


class ChatRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ChatRoom
        fields = ['id', 'owner', 'picture', 'number_of_users', 'messages']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import this with:

```
from authentication.models import User
```

But it is usually better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model. Indeed, in the settings you specify this as:

```
# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
```

and then use the settings instead:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

Regardless what option you decide, likely you have set the "source root" in your IDE on the wrong directory. This should be the `chat_app_backend` in the `chat_app_backend`. It might also be better to give the directories a different name, especially if a directory or file has the same name as its parent directory, this can introduce a lot of confusion.

Comment: is there some way to use the User model without using the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Comment: @sneakydude: that would be horrible code design. But as said, there are two ways to solve it. But the former is only fixing the specific problem. The `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a setting used by a lot of Django packages to link things to... the user model you use to represent the user.

Comment: ohh can we use the fields related to the custom user model as well?

Comment: also should i use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL everywhere i used from authentication.models import User?

Comment: @sneakydude: yes, normally you use the setting to refer to the user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model if you then later change your user model, you can effectively swap in a different user model.

Comment: I have edited my question, its giving me an error even when I try to import a serializer from my authentication app's serializers.py to my chat app's serializers.py

Comment: @sneakydude: you should import it with `from authentication.serializers import UserSerializer`. The root directory should be the ane immediately above the `authentication`, so it is always `from authentication...`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
import sys

# Add the chat_app_backend directory to the Python path
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from chat_app_backend.authentication.models import User
```

`os.path.abspath(__file__)` gives you the absolute path of the current file which is models.py. Then `os.path.dirname()` function returns the directory containing the file which here is chat directory. Finally we use `sys.path.append()` to add it to the Python path.